# ES6 modules: code execution "smell" with export

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm not a wizard with JavaScript by any stretch, and I've been wrapping my head around Vue.js which uses ES6 heavily. When looking at how vue-router is implemented, the module declaration looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import TestComponent from '@/components/TestComponent'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/test',
      name: 'Test',
      component: TestComponent
    }
  ]
})
```

Where the main.js has an "import Router from './router'" pointing to my /router/index.js, followed by adding this "Router" instance to the Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#appl',
  router: Router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Now this, I all understand to a degree. My index.js in /rounter exports a new "Router" from vue-router, initializing it with the specified routes. The bit I don't fully understand, and seems like a smell is the location of "Vue.use(Router)" in this router's index.js file above the export. From my take on this, the code in ./router/index.js will be executed when the Vue instance is initialized based on the "router: Router" assignment.

The question I have is whether this is a proper place to put the Vue.use? The reason I ask is because I also want to use vue-intl for localization and i18n. To do this I will need a Vue.use(VueIntl) after an import, however I will also need to do things like register messages for the various supported languages. Should executable code ever reside in a component outside of any effective scope like that?

Comment: *"Should executable code ever reside in a component outside of any effective scope like that?"* It's not "outside any effective scope." It's in the module's scope. That's where you put module-level initialization. (Posting as comment rather than answer in case there's a Vue-specific aspect to this.)

Comment: note you're passing a "constructor", not an instance, so it's fully ready to go at parse time.

Comment: Is it a constructor?? It looks like an instance of the Router object imported from vue-router, initialized with the routes defined.  From what I've read of Modules is that they are to be used to compartment-ize reusable code, but seeing stuff like this just seems weird. I want to include a Router in my Vue app instance, yet these dependent modules are importing Vue and making calls against it. How these resolve down to the same instance is beyond me...